# Ghostscript - Can resize padding be applied to end of image rather than top?

Tags: pdf, scaling, ghostscript

I am trying to convert a PDF doc whose page size is A4 wide but several cm's short of being A4 long into Tiff.

Using GS I can happily convert it to A4 TIFF but the image is padded at the top with a 3cm white space.
This leaves a rather ugly white banner at the very top.

Is there anyway to get GS to pad at the bottom of a page not the top?

I am using GS 9.04 on Linux and use the following conversion command.

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFFitPage -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDRESOLUTION -sOutputFile=x.pdf y.pdf
```

I see the same problem if I do just a pdf to pdf resize conversion

```
gs -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=x.pdf -dPDFFitPage y.pdf
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the image isn't 'padded' in the original PDF document. The 'padding' isn't applied by Ghostscript, its present in the original PDF file, the white space at the top of the PDF page is rendered as white space in the TIFF file.

You can set the media size to be the size you need (and set -dFIXEDMEDIA, so that it doesn't get changed) and then render the file. The 'white space' will then fall off the top of the media, and won't get rendered. You'll have to figure out what the MEDIAHEIGHT parameter needs to be of course.

If you do this, don't set -dPDFFitPage, as this will scale the whole page down to fit the new media size, defeating the purpose of changing the media size.....

Comment: Thanks for replying but the problem is that the original PDF has no padding.  In the original PDF the first line of text is at the very top of the page, and the pdf page is 26cm long. When the tiff is produced then the page length is A4 (29.7cm) but the first line is now 3.7 cm down the page.  Hence any extension to the page space has been applied at the top.

Comment: Well Ghostscript should honour the media size request *if* the PDF file has a Media size of 'not exactly A4'. However, if it has a Media size of A4 but a CropBox or similar then Ghostscript will use the Media size, not the CropBox, for the Page Size which will lead to what you describe. See next answer.

Comment: I agree with Ken, it's not "padding" per se, but the way the image model is anchored at the bottom left. You're really going to have to specify the media size so ghstscript knows where to cut the top off.

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming that the PDF file has a MediaBox of A4, but supplied a 'less than A4' CrtopBox, then you want to set -dUseCropBox. And still not set -dFitPage.

You should also *not* set -sPAPERSIZE.

If this is not the case then I'm going to have to see an example PDF file.